# Macro copies from one workbook into another, Runs with no error but sometimes doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel

I am slowly learning VBA in Excel on my own so I'm sure this code can be picked a part. Basically users fill this area with info and click a button that in the background copies the data they populate, opens a new workbook and pastes it in the next open row. There are many users, and for some it works, for others it runs with no error but their info is not pasted in the new. location. Most of the stuff at the end is just reformatting, but I didn't want to take it out in case it could be a part of the problem.

```
Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
        Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
        Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
        Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function


Sub FF_Temp_Upload()
'
' FF_Temp_Upload Macro
'
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Workbk As Workbook
    Set Workbk = ThisWorkbook
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim Cell As Long
    Dim Ret As String

    LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Ret = IsWorkBookOpen("Location of the 2nd workbook/OVS Upload Template.xlsx")


    If Ret = True Then
        MsgBox "Template is currently being updated elsewhere. Please try again."
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Workbooks.Open FileName:= _
    "Location of the 2nd workbook/OVS Upload Template.xlsx"    
    End If

    Workbk.Activate
    Range("A2:C" & LR).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("OVS Upload Template.xlsx").Activate

    If Range("A2") = "" Then
        Range("A2").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Else
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If

    Workbk.Activate
    Range("H2:H" & LR).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("OVS Upload Template.xlsx").Activate

    If Range("L2") = "" Then
        Range("L2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Else
        Range("L2").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$100000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

    LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("B2:B" & LR) = "=text(left(A2,8),""00000000"")"
    Range("B2:B" & LR).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("C2:C" & LR) = "=""DCG""&MID(A2,9,4)"
    Range("C2:C" & LR).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("D2:D" & LR).Select
    Selection.Formula = "DT"
    Range("I2:I" & LR).Select
    Selection.Formula = "730"
    Range("M2:M" & LR).Select
    Selection.Formula = "MAJOH73"


    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Workbk.Activate

    MsgBox "Articles Uploaded"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not refer to `Worksheets` anywhere in your code. Thus, for some users, it works and for some it does not.

For those who works - their Excel file was saved with the correct Worksheet selected.

For those who does not work - their Excel file was saved with wrong Worksheet selected. Thus, when it is opened, the `ActiveSheet` is the wrong one and the code works there.

---

To fix it (quick and dirty) rewrite your code, refering the worksheet like this:

```
Worksheets("MyWorksheet").Range("$A$1:$M$100000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1
```

Then try to avoid `Selection` and `ActiveSheet` - [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). At the end, each range or cell should be with refered Worksheet. Like this:

```
With Worksheets("MyName")
    .Range("D2:D" & LR).Formula = "DT"
    .Range("I2:I" & LR).Formula = "730"
    .Range("M2:M" & LR).Formula = "MAJOH73"
End With
```

Comment: So do I set MyWorkSheet as a variable to activeworksheet, and use that whenever the macro should be switching between workbooks?

Comment: @Matjoh33 - see the edited version of the answer. Each range or cell in your code should refer to a worksheet by name or index to make it work. Or simply tell your colleagues, that they should always save the Excel file, using a specific worksheet as selected one (check which one it is for the cases where it works). Then it will work for everyone.

Comment: Okay I believe I understand now. So switching between workbooks is not enough, I have to express the worksheet I am working in as well.. thanks for the help!

Comment: @Matjoh33 - once you fix your code, put it here - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ it will get reviewed and you will see some nice ideas :)